# How can I count / view all fast-path sockets on windows server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, tcp, socket, loopback

In case you're not familiar, fast path loopback sockets:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path/

How can I count how many connections of this type a system currently have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering self for future seekers (partial answer though):

There's no way to count it on windows (at least from what I found), but you can count sockets that user requested to be fast-path but windows rejected and used plain loopback instead. So if you know how many fast-path sockets were *supposed* to be opened, you can use that counter to see if any of them failed.

To access that counter open perfmon.exe and add the following counter:

```
TCPIP Performance Diagnostics/TCP connect requests fallen off loopback fast path
```

Leaving the question opened for now in case someone have a better answer.